# How to retain cells edited on setColumns()?

Tags: tabulator

I have tabulator working with excel like tabs at the bottom that change the columns shown. It also highlights any row that has been edited and highlights each individual cell that has been edited. But when I switch tabs, the edited rows maintains their highlights, but if I switch back to the previous tab, the cells that were edited are no longer highlighted.

```
this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs['example-table'], {
        data: [],
        height: "500px",
        index:"title",
        placeholder: "No Data Set",
        footerElement: $("#table-controls").get(0),
        columns: this.gtabColumns,
        cellEdited: function(cell) {
            if((_.isNil(cell.getOldValue()) || _.isEmpty(cell.getOldValue())) 
                    && (_.isNil(cell.getValue()) || _.isEmpty(cell.getValue()))) {
                return;
            }
            $(cell.getElement()).css("background-color", "#67f165");
            $(cell.getRow().getElement()).css("background-color", "#d1fbd0");
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to directly  manipulate the elements in the table from inside the ***cellEdited*** function.

Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM it is not safe to try and manipulate any elements inside the table directly. You should only change the cell element in the ***formatter*** in the column definition or the ***rowFormatter*** for rows. anywhere else is unsafe.

In your case you would want a cell formatter like this:

```
var editedCellFormatter = function(cell){
    if(cell.oldValue !== null){
       cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#67f165";
    }

    return cell.getValue();
}
```

Which you can then assign in the column definition:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:editedCellFormatter}
```